# Send Contents of a Div via jQuery

Tags: jquery, post, escaping

I'd really like to take all of the html in a div (contains many other divs, form elements, etc), urlencode it (maybe) and then do an ajax post to a server side handler so that I can save the exact state of what the user is seeing.

I would then like to be able to take that string that I've saved in a database and send it back in response to an ajax call in the future.

Should I use something like the following?

```
var contents = escape($('#myDiv').html());
```

Then do an ajax post operation to a server side handler?  Would escape ensure that I am not passing back any special characters that would mess up the ajax call?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: That sounds like it should work. Why not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about escaping the data if you're sending it as a POST parameter.  If it was a GET, it would actually be appearing in the URI and you would need to make sure everything was escaped.

This is all you really need to do:

```
$.post('/my_handler', {'html': $('#myDiv').html()}. function(data){
     //do something with data     
});
```

Your script responding at `/my_handler` will just need to check the 'html' post parameter for that string.  For example, if you're using PHP you would just check `$_POST['html']`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this:

function htmlEncode(value){ 
          return $('< div / >').text(value).html(); 
        }

function htmlDecode(value){ 
          return $('< div />').html(value).text(); 
        }

var contents = htmlEncode($('#myDiv').html());